# Is it a good practice to put new widget on top of old widget during update in PySide

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside

I was given a codebase in which the labels updates overtime but when it updates, it simply covers on top of the old label.

In general is this a good practice?

```
    def drawAllListeners(self):

        row = 1
        col = 0

        labels = ["Del", "Status", "Name", "Display handler", "Minimum report interval"]
        colspans = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
        for (span, label) in zip(colspans, labels):
            label_text = QtGui.QLabel("<b>" + label + "</b>")
            label_text.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.RichText)
            self.main_grid.addWidget(label_text, row, col, 1, span)
            col += span

        for k, l in self.target_state.getListenersDict().iteritems():
            self.drawOneListener(k)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not a good idea because the number of children widgets increases and increases which will eventually lead to memory problems. Changing the text of the old label widgets is the way to go?